# Replacement Rackmount ears?

Tags: rack, rackmount, hardware

I have some 1u and 2u cases where the ears mysteriously disappeared for them, so the cases are loose.
My googlefu seems to be weak, are there places that sell "generic" rack ears for 2u cases, or replacement ears for dell switches?

Outside of a machine shop does anyone have any suggestions on how to get replacement ears?

thanks!

Comment: I was about to say "Bunnings" (which is a general household hardware supplier where I live), but seeing your comment about a machine shop makes me think you've already thought of this :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to find something suitable you could try asking Dell even if it's just so you can kill an hour or so trying to get through to the right person. Failing that check out some of the smaller "engineering" or metalworking companies in your area. They're trivial to make (cut, bend, drill) and shouldn't cost too much.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use the rack rails that are basically little shelves for each side of the rack, just slide the servers onto them:

http://www.server-rack-online.com/universal-server-rack-rails.html